# Force div with overflow-y to always show newest (bottom of div)

Tags: javascript, css

I have created an action-log which is supposed to keep you up to date about your actions. So everytime you click on the button it shows you what you just did, but the problem is that it won't show the newest message automatically. Is it possible to show the newest message everytime you click on the button?

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a8ey2ucm/1/

```
<div id="log">

</div>

<button onclick="actionBtn();">
  Click here
</button>

function actionBtn()
{
    var log = document.getElementById('log');
  var action = document.createElement("p");
  var actionNode = document.createTextNode("You have rolled");

  action.appendChild(actionNode);
  log.appendChild(action);
}
```

Comment: Newest message?, not clear what do you mean by that. And your jsFiddle is working fine.

Comment: @frnt The newest "You have rolled" message, now when you spam the button it shows the old message.

Comment: Okay @C.Ronaldo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there are countless answers for this on the web. However

```
function actionBtn()
{
    var log = document.getElementById('log');
    var action = document.createElement("p");
    var actionNode = document.createTextNode("You have rolled");

    action.appendChild(actionNode);
    log.appendChild(action);

    log.scrollTop = log.scrollHeight;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Tried to look it up, but couldn't find it, maybe because of the way I put down the question

Btw: log.scrollTop = log.scrollHeight; without the previous code is working also.

Comment: You are right. Did it in a hurry. Didint even notice you already declared log as a variable :) Edited for future reference